# Stopping sound in -onExit method of child?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I have three classes, let's call them A,B and C. Class A has a CCLayer class added called B. B has a CCLayer child added too, called C. Now, C plays a sound effect that I would like to stop when scene A is replaced. I assumed that if scene A is replaced by calling -replaceScene, all its children are being removed and cleaned up as well. So I tried to put my piece of code that should stop the sound into the -onExit method of class C. However -onExit is never called on any of the children of the replaced scene. Why is that, and how can I solve this ?

All the methods (stopping the sound etc.) work, I just don't know where to call them. The situation is basically the following: I am in my main scene and if I tap the "main menu" button, I want its children to stop playing any sounds. How do the children know their parent is being released ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If onExit isn't called for a node it means that it wasn't removed from the scene hierarchy. This points to a memory leak, specifically a retain cycle. You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint in the CCScene's dealloc method. If it doesn't get hit when changing scenes, you're leaking the scene.

Comment: But cclayer objects are autorelease objects, so there should not be any problem, right ? I usually call -node or -alloc -initwithsomething -autorelease which should do the job properly. However it is a mystery to me why -onExit is not called...

Comment: The `-dealloc` method is not called at all. What could be the cause ?

Comment: -onEnter also seems to bump it up by 1... Why is that and what could I do about that ?

Comment: ok I figured it out. I had to put [super onExit] into my -onExit method in order for the class to be dealloced which seems very strange to me... Could you maybe explain why ?